Clerk Middleware Causing Issues in Production, Works Fine Locally
Clerk middleware is causing issues on the production website, but works correctly in my local development build.
I need the middleware to lock the user on either the authentication page or the form page. It is supposed to allow access to the routes once the form is approved.
My website has a button that says "continue". when the button is tapped, on a production build, it's just stuck on the page and doesn't do anything. on local build, it either takes me to the form page, or takes me to the dashboard page if Account status is APPROVED. i'm using the latest version of clerk (6.9.6)
I also added Content-Security-Policy as shown in https://clerk.com/docs/security/clerk-csp, but it didn't help
Also, let me know if there is a better way of doing this please
This is my middleware that I implemented using Clerk Documentation:
const fetchFormData = async (userId: string): Promise<CoachOnboardingFormData | null> => {
  if (!userId) return null;
  const userFormRef = ref(database, `accountStatus/${userId}`);

  try {
    const snapshot = await get(userFormRef);

    if (snapshot.exists()) {
      const formData = snapshot.val() as CoachOnboardingFormData;
      return formData;
    } else {
      return null; // No form data found
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error occurred fetching onboarding form: ${error}`);
    return null;
  }
};

// Public routes that do not require authentication
const isPublicRoute = createRouteMatcher(["/"]);

export default clerkMiddleware(async (auth, req) => {
  const { userId, redirectToSignIn } = await auth();

  // Allow public routes without authentication
  if (isPublicRoute(req)) {
    return NextResponse.next();
  }

  // Redirect unauthenticated users to the sign-in page
  if (!userId) {
    return redirectToSignIn();
  }

  // Allow access to the form page if the user is signed in
  if (req.nextUrl.pathname === "/form") {
    return NextResponse.next();
  }

  // Handle account approval logic for other authenticated routes
  try {
    // Add timeout for the entire middleware operation
    const timeoutPromise = new Promise<null>((_, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => reject(new Error('Timeout fetching form data')), 5000); // 5 seconds timeout
    });

    const formData = await Promise.race([
      fetchOnboardingFormData(userId),
      timeoutPromise
    ]);

    // On successful form data fetch
    if (formData?.accountStatus === AccountStatus.APPROVED) {
      return NextResponse.next(); // Allow navigation for approved users
    }

    // Redirect non-approved users to the form page
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/form", req.url));
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Middleware error:", error);
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/", req.url)); // Fallback redirect
  }
});

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    // Skip Next.js internals and all static files, unless found in search params
    '/((?!_next|[^?]*\\.(?:html?|css|js(?!on)|jpe?g|webp|png|gif|svg|ttf|woff2?|ico|csv|docx?|xlsx?|zip|webmanifest)).*)',
    // Always run for API routes
    '/(api|trpc)(.*)',
  ],
};

